# C#.Net Casting and Instantiating Memory Allocation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, memory, casting

Can some one explain me what is the different between this type of usage as performance  vice. These are simply function callings on two inherited classes. First one uses the advantage of inheritance and second one discard it.

```
class ClassA 
{
    public void X()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassA: X()");
    }
}

class ClassB : ClassA
{
    new public void X()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassB: X()");
    }
}

class CheckMemory
{
    public void testMemory ()
    {  
        //Code block 1
        ClassB bob1 = new ClassB();
        ClassA aob1 = bob1;

        aob1.X();
        bob1.X();

        //Code block 2 
        ClassB bob2 = new ClassB();
        ClassA aob2 = new ClassA();

        aob2.X();
        bob2.X();
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the question? If the output is not what you expect, show the output and show what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case instead of allocating a new Object we are reusing it i.e. both bob1 and aob1  are pointing to the same instance of an object on the Heap.

Where as in the second block you are creating two different instance of two different classes they occupy two memory locations in the heap , instead of the first one.

So the first one is memory efficient then the first , I hope this explanation helps.